# Should I use CSS, javascript or both to make this fixed element expand the parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that a an element with `position:fixed` acts like its parent element with `position:relative` (Or no position specified) doesn't exist, and that's my concern. I've seen the very same question being asked here on StackOverflow, but not the very same problem.

I have a wrapper, an element with relative position, and an element with a fixed position inside the relative element. The element with fixed position should expand the element with relative position as you scroll the page, but what's happening is that when you scroll the page, the element with fixed position will go out of the main container, instead of expanding. How can I make the main element push the container element bellow, instead of getting an offset?

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/T2PL5/515/

Here my code:

CSS

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: 650px;
    background: green;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}

.main {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">wrapper
    <div class="sidebar"> Sidebar
        <div class="main">main</div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: _The fixed element should expand the relative element, as you scroll the page._ It's not clear what this means, but `fixed` position is relative to the viewport -- and setting an element to `position:fixed` necessarily removes it from the normal flow (including its parent)

Comment: I agree with @KevinBoucher, I don't know what you mean by that either. Was going to say the same thing.

Comment: @KevinBoucher is correct, "`fixed` position is relative to the viewport" and the element cannot be contained within the parent.

Comment: Got it now? One element with fixed position, inside a an element with relative position, or no position specified.

Comment: That edit didn't really clear things up. Why don't you explain more about the problem you are having or what you are trying to achieve. "The fixed element should expand the relative element, as you scroll the page" doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I'm opened to edit suggestions.

Comment: I think the OP wants `.sidebar` to contain `.main` while `.main` is fixed to the window. So you want `.sidebar` to grow in height as you scroll down the page? I can't imagine a CSS solution for this. You will need to use JavaScript to programmatically adjust the height of `.sidebar` based on the bottom offset of it and the `.main` div

Comment: Yes, that's right, but it probably should be javascript + css, as `.main` gotta have the `position:fixed`

Comment: I need a starting point, know somewhere I can find resources?